# How to know when parallel HTTP requests are fulfilled in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, grand-central-dispatch

I need to run some code only **after** requesting multiple HTTP resources for gathering some data.

I've read a lot of documentation and I've found out I should use GCD and *dispatch groups*:

1. Create a group with `dispatch_group_create()`
2. *For each* request:

   - Enter the dispatch group with `dispatch_group_enter()`
   - Run the request
   - When receiving a response, leave the group with `dispatch_group_leave()`
3. Wait with `dispatch_group_wait()`
4. Release the group with `dispatch_release()`

Yet I'm not sure if this practice could have some pitfalls – or is there a better way to wait for parallels requests being finished?

The code below looks working well:

```
    // Just send a request and call the when finished closure
    func sendRequest(url: String, whenFinished: () -> Void) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url))
        let task  = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            whenFinished()
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    let urls = ["http://example.com?a",
        "http://example.com?b",
        "http://example.com?c",
        "http://example.com?d",
        "http://invalid.example.com"]

    var fulfilledUrls: Array<String> = []

    let group = dispatch_group_create();

    for url in urls {
        dispatch_group_enter(group)

        sendRequest(url, {
            () in
            fulfilledUrls.append(url)
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
        })

    }

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    for url in fulfilledUrls { println(url) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, this is the basic idea, although you would ideally use `dispatch_group_notify` instead of `dispatch_group_wait` since `dispatch_group_wait` blocks the calling thread until the group completes, whereas `dispatch_group_notify` will call a block when the group completes *without* blocking the calling thread in the interim.